# Can women use hair threading machine?

Tags: practical-islam, women

Nowadays hair threading machines for women are also available in market.Can women use these machines to remove hair from her face and from other parts of body.? 
Is there any restriction according to islamic point of view.?

Answer (score -2):

Is the Islam threading for women are not prohibited and some privileges that they remove hair from their face via any source like threading machine or any cream